# Can't load CSV from Drive to Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the following cypher code:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "https://drive.google.com/file/d/12DiEwM8XatMZBXA6TdekxWl8qrsgVj3l/view?usp=sharing" AS requests RETURN requests
```

and getting the following error:

```
At https://drive.google.com/file/d/12DiEwM8XatMZBXA6TdekxWl8qrsgVj3l/view?usp=sharing @ position 1691 -  there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That isn't supported. This is what I read: 'docs-fwds":'
```

Please advise how to fix it, I want to be able to load a simple CSV file from Drive to Neo4j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the download link instead of the sharing link. This works for me:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=12DiEwM8XatMZBXA6TdekxWl8qrsgVj3l&export=download" as row
RETURN row LIMIT 5
```

I got the download link by clicking on the download icon, which redirects you. You have to be fast to copy the redirect link and it should work. Perhaps there is a method with which you could reconstruct the query manually, so you don't have to be extremely fast to copy the download link, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: How did you get the link? From where?

Comment: The file needs to be open to public. Load CSV doesn't handle authentication. Next, you can open the CSV file with the sharing link you have provided for me. Last, click on the download icon and you should be redirected for a second before the download starts. The redirect link is what you should use. Looking at the URL, you can try to replace the id in the link I provided and see if that works for you. Anyhow, the file needs to be public ally available at the moment of import.

Comment: Or just use this site: https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/home to get the download link.